# Render VSE frame and 3D scene seperately in script background mode?

Tags: python, rendering, video-sequence-editor

Does anyone how to render VSE seperate and and 3D scene seperately in the background mode?  is it even possible? In UI render `bpy.ops.render` renders whatever `SpaceType` was last active.

Is it the same `bpy.ops.render` operator with using an active `SpaceType`?

I tried `bpy.ops.render.opengl` aswel because thats python tool tip for VSE render image menu item, but it's `write_still=True`  doesn't seem to work.

I want to:

render frames on the 3Dscene

1. Render frames on the 3Dscene.
2. Push them to different Channel Strips in VSE.
3. Export the VSE preview/output at a certain frame to disk or a texture

And I want to do this recursively, dynamically via script in background mode.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is possible if you run script to change settings inside Blender scene https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667314/python-script-with-arguments-for-command-line-blender

Comment: yh. I understand the render code. but which setting seperates the VSE from 3DScene?

Comment: `scene.render.use_sequencer`

Comment: Noice!!! Thank you vm!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not depending on active space. If `scene.render.use_sequencer` is *true*, Blender will render from sequencer (VSE) but only if it has image strips.

In UI you can find it here:

[image]